# bin/console doctrine:database:create does not work

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4

hello everyone here I am blocking on a little worry, I just created a project synfony 3.4.

when running the following command

`bin / console doctrine: database: create`

he does not spend anything

Can you help me please

**parameters.yml**

```
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: 8000
    database_name: symfony
    database_user: root
    database_password: null
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
```

I would like to create my database

Comment: Run with `-vvv` to see the very verbose output. Any errors? Update the question with the output.

Comment: thanks for your answer, there is no error display.

I think I should miss a package but I do not know which one.

Comment: This is not reproducible in any way. Database port 8000?

Comment: I do not know I try with port 8080, 8000 and null.

nothing changes. little pressure I'm on macos I do not know if it changes something

Comment: I do not know I try with port 8080, 8000 and null.

nothing changes. little pressure I'm on macos I do not know if it changes something

Comment: MySQL usually operates on port 3306. You’re missing fundamental things here.